# German characters sending data using POST method from ASP page to PHP page

Tags: c#, php, asp.net

I have a problem with sending data from ASP with the POST Method to a PHP page.
I would like to send mail with names. And since I live in Austria the names are in German and we have some Special characters. These characters don't arrive write.

I'm still pretty new to programming with C# btw. I had the Website before in Java-Script but I had to connect it with a database and therefore I switched to C# and now I'm like a "babe in the woods".

```
       this.hdnDaten.Value = "ÄÖÜ|äöü|ß|é|@";

// mit POST versuchen
   using (var client = new WebClient())
   {
       var postData = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
       postData.Add("von", this.hdnVon.Value);
       postData.Add("an", this.hdnAn.Value);
       postData.Add("betreff", this.hdnBetreff.Value);
       postData.Add("daten", this.hdnDaten.Value);
       byte[] response = client.UploadValues("http://xxxxxx.php", "POST", postData);
       var responsebody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
   }
```

And this is how the characters (in this.hdnDaten.Value) from above arrive in the mail-body:

> Ã„Ã–Ãœ|Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼|ÃŸ|Ã©|@

Does anybody know what I can do to get the same characters in the end?

Edit 20143013: I think I have a clue: I have to encode the postData into ANSI (Codepage 1252). I tried do do this, but it doesn't work. Does anybody have an Idea how I could do this?

Edit 20140320: I don't even dare to give you the answer: I was looking all the time in the wrong place (somewhat like MH370): The problem was with the receiving side of the mail (I was using a POP3-Viewer for testing); when I downloaded the mail to Outlook everything was OK. The funny thing was that this didn't happen in the original (Javascript) Version that's why I was looking at the wrong place.

Thanks
Eddie

Comment: Your string seems to be like encoded in `UTF8` and decoded in `ISO-8859-2`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting client.Encoding to UTF-8 before calling UploadValues. Also ensure that you read the text as UTF-8 on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try `this.hdnDaten.Value = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("ÄÖÜ|äöü|ß|é|@");` on your post parameters.

on PHP you'll need to decode the parameters via `html_entity_decode`